# How to declare an array using get-date?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to declare an array of dates in powershell, it's not a continuous range, so I cant do anything clever with loops.

I've tried using the array notation with a call to get-date, as below, but this returns an error

```
$logDateList = 
@(Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 08 -Day 22 -Hour 13
,Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 08 -Day 20 -Hour 22)
```

How can I declare an array of dates in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap each `Get-Date` in brackets:

```
$logDateList = @((Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 08 -Day 22 -Hour 13),(Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 08 -Day 20 -Hour 22))
```

Comment: *Parenthesis*.  Brackets are `[ ]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 In the UK `( )` are known as brackets and `[ ]` are square brackets. Yet another difference between English and American grammar :)

Comment: @JamesC the reason they are needed is to stop the `, get-date..` comma from turning the whole thing into an array parameter to the first Get-Date cmdlet. They "override the default precedence and associativity" of the comma, and by the [Windows PowerShell Language Specification 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389) section 7.1.1, that makes them `Grouping parentheses`. ;-)  PowerShell is an American language after all

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that you should still use a loop for this to save yourself some code duplication:

```
$logDateList = '20 Aug 2017 22:00','22 Aug 2017 22:13' | ForEach-Object { Get-Date $_ }
```

Example using text for months in the interests of avoiding regional issues but you could format your dates in whatever way you like that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast a string to a datetime like this:

```
[datetime]'2017-08-22 13:00'
```

and make your array

```
$logDateList = [datetime]'2017-08-22 13:00', [datetime]'2017-08-20 22:00'
```

and if you're doing that, make it one array of string dates, and cast to an array of datetime

```
[datetime[]] $logDateList = @(
    '2017-08-22 13:00', 
    '2017-08-20 22:00'
)
```

I put them in ISO standard yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm order to avoid US/UK parsing confusion.